# A problem with Dash to Panel extention

Tags: appmenu, 21.10

I recently activated on my ubuntu 21.10 the Dash to Panel extention and I noticed that in the application menu (left down corner or Super key + A) it doesn't show the applications, it only allows me to switch between windows.
How do I fix this?

Comment: If you look at the user reviews at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/ you'll get your answer.